# Unable to add MYSQL System DSN on ODBC 64bit

Tags: mysql, odbc, mysql-connector

I am trying to add new MYSQL system DSN with no luck. There are no errors. After adding in the details and when i click OK it completes with no error but i do not see it in the list of DSN.

MYSQL connector driver version 8.0.21 x64bit has been installed. I am able to create other DSN (sql server, access, excel etc..) just not MYSQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using '.' in the Name and that was causing issue. Turns out there are some special chars that are not supported in the DataSource Name when setting up ODBC connection. :|